# Intrusion alert system for rugged environments iot, sensors

Tags: sensors, microsoft-windows-iot, google-iot-core

We are developing an IoT based intrusion alert system for the agricultural field.
The plan is to have vibration sensors installed over the fence on the periphery of agricultural land
Required capabilities of system

- Detect any vibration over the fence
- Detect Wire cut over the fence
- Adjustable/controllable vibration sensitivity
- Rugged as it will be installed in open field
- Filter vibrations due to weather conditions such as wind, rain, etc.
- Differentiate between human and vibration activity (Nice to have)
- Power supply to the sensor: Solar or battery
- Send Email/SMS alerts for any intrusion.
- Packaging
- Data from the IoT device will be sent through the GSM module installed in it. We are considering Particle Electron for this. Don't know if it works with 3rd party SIM.
- IoT device must send location.

What I have tried:

We have developed a prototype with below components

- IoT device: Particle Photon
- Vibration Sensor: SW-420 (Seems to be suitable for prototyping only)
- EMail alert: Device -> Particle Cloud -> Microsoft Azure IoT Hub -> Azure Logic App -> Twilio Email Connector
- SMS alert: Device -> Particle Cloud -> Microsoft Azure IoT Hub -> Azure Logic App -> Plivo SMS Connector

SW-420 is connected to digital pin of IoT device.
When a SW-420 sensor is touched, it generates digital value of 1 which is then published/pushed to Particle cloud, thereby sending an email/sms.

This works at a prototype level.

We are looking for below information

- Vibration sensor covering capabilities mentioned above
- IoT device for the above scenario.
- PCB design
- Packaging
- Is there a way we can directly send data to Azure from IoT device rather than using Manufacturer cloud such as Particle Cloud.
- Looking for a system with low maintenance.

Please share your views on any of the items mentioned above as it will help us develop the system.

Comment: Hi Praveen, please take a look at the info in the box above—our site isn't really ideal for posts with multiple questions in one go, as they're not as specific or helpful. Perhaps you could [edit] to make your question more specific to one of the above bullet points?

Comment: Please, do edit it (read [ask]), as this has the makings of an excellent question.  We have to have rules, but we truly do want to help.